# Android OneSignal Not Playing Custom Notification Sound

Tags: onesignal

I have OneSignal implemented into our app and things are running smoothly. The only thing I can't get working is triggering the push notification with the sound I send with it.

In my res/raw folder I have a sound file called okayy.mp3 (OneSignal approved format).

In one signal I include the file name as "okayy" but it just plays the default sound. I have even tried setting the default OneSignal sound as their docs recommended "onesignal_default_sound.mp3) and even that is not used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Create a file **keep.xml** in **res/xml** folder and put this code in the file :

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    tools:keep="@raw/okayy"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must Setting up Notification Categories
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-categories#section-setting-up-notification-categories

And choose "sound" category parameter to "okayy"

Answer (score -1):

The answer from @sanuj is correct, but I guess you have to include the file extension, like this:

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    tools:keep="@raw/okayy.mp3"/>
```

Comment: No, you don't have to include it.